# Hibernate: how do I get an entity for juts referencing purposes?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to retrieve an object from Hibernate purely for reading it's values. How should I go about doing this?

get() + evict() + flush()?

Mainly I want to check if a value has been changed:

```
Foo foo = getModifiedFoo();
Foo oldFoo = session.get(Foo.class, foo.getId());
if (foo.getBar() != oldFoo.getBar()) {
    throw YouAFooException();
}
session.saveOrUpdate(foo);
```

I'm guessing this would give me an "Object already in session" exception of some sort so I'm wondering how I should go about doing this.

Comment: You may be able to avoid doing this if you use a version attribute on your objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge()`, which copies the state of a detached entity to its attached counterpart, instead of making a detached entity attached like `saveOrUpdate()` does.